# Refer generic class by name

Tags: scala, reflection, generic-programming, scala-reflect

Consider the case that I want to deserialize a JSON string:

```
def deserialize[T](json)
```

I can provided class that I want to apply the function explicitly while writing code like

```
  class Person(name: String)
  deserialize[Person]("""{ "name": "Jennie" }""")
```

But, what if I need other class, I have to provide it in my code, compile again. I want my program more flexible, it can take a config file that contains name of which class I want to use. So, when ever require a new class, I just need to write the class definition, build it into another jar file, put it in classpath, then restart the program.

```
    val config = ConfigLoader.load("config.txt")
    val className = config.getString("class-to-deserialize")
    deserialize[<from className to type>](json)
```

So, is it possible to do that in scala?

Answer (score 0):

No. But because of type erasure, if you have a function `def deserialize[T](json: String)`, its behavior can't depend on `T` in the first place and it doesn't matter what you pass as the type parameter. You may just need to add a cast at the end.

What *is* possible is to write such a function which also accepts an implicit `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` parameter, in which case you just need to create the parameter from class/type name, and that's entirely possible: just search for questions about this.